# Strange behavior converting dates to UTC dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of numbers that represent dates. These numbers are ordered sequentially in ascending order. For each number, I first convert it to a JavaScript Date object, and from the Date object into a UTC date. The problem is that the UTC dates are NOT ordered sequentially (look at the console log, 468028800000 is less than 468547200000). What's wrong with this code?

```js
var dates = [
  469342800000, 469429200000, 469515600000,
  469602000000, 469688400000, 469774800000
];

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  var d = new Date(dates[i]);
  var dateUTC = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());
  console.log(dates[i], d, dateUTC);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```js
var dateUTC = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay());
```

`getDay()` gives you the day of the week, not the day of the month. You want `getDate()`.